# Password recovery for custom authentication provider

Tags: .net, authentication

I am looking for third party solutions to manage password recovery feature when custom authentication provider is used with support:

- Mail notification with password recovery link
- Link activity expiration in N minutes
- UI customization
- Oauth2 friendly

It can be implemented on top of current provider, but maybe there are proven solutions?

Comment: The exact wording sparked some confusion from my side... Are you looking for a **third-party solution** that supports custom (username/password) authentication and those specific features (something like [Auth0](https://auth0.com/)) or are you looking for a .NET **third-party library** that supports those features in a way that they can be added to your own custom authentication?

Comment: I'm looking only password recovery solution which can be mapped to custom authentication implementation (not based on Membership auth provider).